# How to edit Windows Forms controls from different threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer

I'm trying to make a c# IRC client. My problem:
I have a `TextBox` declared in the Form class, and I have a timer that executes `OnTimedEvent` method, which should edit the `TextBox`.

```
System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
aTimer.Interval = 500;
aTimer.Enabled = true;


public void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    string inputLine = reader.ReadLine();
    tab1text.Text = inputLine;
}
```

I get an error that the object I want to edit, was created by another thread..

The reader is a `StreamReader` that gets data from a TCP connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tab1text.Invoke(new Action(delegate(){ tab1text.Text = inputLine }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) to edit UI from another thread.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there should be a semicolon:

```
tab1text.Invoke(new Action(delegate(){ tab1text.Text = inputLine; }));
```